# BST implementation in rust

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree

I am looking for some feedback on my implementation of binary search tree in rust and I would appreciate someone taking the time to go through it and suggest any improvements or corrections as they see fit. More specifically I am concerned about if I should have `Clone` derives in the `BST` and `Node` structs since I am not using them here.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

use std::fmt::Debug;
fn main() {
    let mut bst = BST::new(3_i32);
    bst.append(4);
    bst.append(1);
    bst.append(12);
    bst.display();
}
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BST<T> {
    root: Box<Node<T>>,
}
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> BST<T>
where
    T: PartialOrd + Debug + Clone,
{
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        let root = Box::new(Node {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        });
        Self { root }
    }
    pub fn append(&mut self, new_val: T) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
            val: new_val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        });
        Self::push_node(new_node, &mut self.root);
    }
    // Private and recursive method
    // recursively search through every node until the value is inserted
    fn push_node(new_node: Box<Node<T>>, current_node: &mut Box<Node<T>>) {
        let ref new_val = new_node.val;
        let ref current_val = current_node.val;
        if *current_val <= *new_val {
            if let Some(ref mut left) = current_node.left {
                Self::push_node(new_node, left);
            } else {
                current_node.left = Some(new_node);
            }
        } else if *current_val > *new_val {
            if let Some(ref mut right) = current_node.right {
                Self::push_node(new_node, right);
            } else {
                current_node.right = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
    }

    fn display(&self) {
        println!("{:#?}", self);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks good for a first project. Most of the review to follow ranges from debatable to nitpicky.

#### Representation

It's unusual that `BST` can't represent an empty tree because it always has at least one `Node` in it. Most data structures have no problem representing emptiness. You use `Option<_>` inside `Node`; there's no apparent reason not to use it in `BST` as well. Doing this also lets you simplify `push_node` by making the non-recursive case – an empty `Option` – the same between left and right trees.

If you have not already, please read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html). This short book will cover a lot of mistakes you may make or have already made when trying to create data structures in Rust.

#### Traits

What traits to implement is really up to you. That said, it's a good idea to implement `Clone`, `Debug` and `Default` for almost all types. `Clone` and `Debug` can be `#[derive]`d; `Default` needs its own `impl` because [the derived bounds on `T` are too conservative](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925).

`Eq`, `Hash`, `Ord`, `PartialEq`, and `PartialOrd` also seem to make sense here and all can be `#[derive]`d.

For a challenge, implement `FromIterator` and `IntoIterator`, which are as close as Rust has to a "collections" API. Again, the too-many-lists book will help you here.

#### Construction

By convention ([C-COMMON-TRAITS](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#types-eagerly-implement-common-traits-c-common-traits)), `new` (if it exists) should usually take no arguments and do the same thing as the `Default` trait (if implemented). If you implement `Default` on `BST`, you can write `new` by just calling `Default::default()`. Additional constructors should be named descriptively: a constructor that creates a BST with one element might be called `from_value`.

#### `impl` bounds

In general, only write bounds for the functions where they are used. `new` and `append` clearly don't need `T: Debug` and none of them need `T: Clone`. You can either put the specific bounds on the functions themselves, or split the functions among `impl` blocks with different bounds.

#### `PartialOrd` vs. `Ord`

Partial ordering is not a strong enough guarantee for a binary search tree: if items cannot be ordered relative to each other, they can't be reliably inserted or retrieved from the tree. Therefore the traversal algorithms should require `T: Ord`, not `T: PartialOrd`.

#### `append`

In Rust, `append` usually means a method of the signature `fn(&mut self, other: &mut Self)`; that is, one that cannibalizes another data structure of the same type. (As far as I know, this meaning is unique to Rust.) The function you call `append` would probably be called `insert` (as in `HashSet`, for example). There's also an `Extend` trait that you might implement in any of several ways; see the [standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) for examples.

#### `ref` patterns

You use a number of `ref` patterns that are not really necessary. Some people dislike all `ref` patterns. I don't personally have an issue with them in an `if let` or `match`, even though they technically aren't needed due to the questionably named "pattern ergonomics" feature (you can use `if let Some(f) = &mut foo` instead of `if let Some(ref mut f) = foo`; the `Some` becomes transparent). However, I recommend against using `ref` in a trivial case like `let new_val = &new_node.val`.

#### `if let` and `match`

If you have an `if let` with an `else` clause, consider turning it into a `match`, especially if one or both branches are short.

#### `std::cmp::Ordering`

Instead of an `if` chain where you test separately `a <= b` and `a > b`, call `a.cmp(&b)` (or `T::cmp(&a, &b)`) and `match` on the [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html). This reduces the chance of accidentally writing a comparison backwards or forgetting a case. Note also that in the original version of `push_node`, if the values were incomparable, the `new_node` would have been simply lost. Using `Ord` instead of `PartialOrd` means this is not possible.

#### `BST`

Conventional capitalization is `Bst` ([C-CASE](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html)).

#### `display`

This method is not useful. Besides having a misleading name (since it uses the `Debug` trait, not `Display`), it's both less obvious in its function and less flexible than simply writing `println!("{:#?}", bst)` (or even shorter: `dbg!(bst)`). There's no particular reason to have a dedicated method for it.

If you mean to have a text representation of a tree for display purposes, but not necessarily the same as the `Debug` implementation, that's precisely what the `Display` trait is for. Implementing `Display` will make `Bst` work in any formatting macro (`format!`, `write!`, etc.), and gives some other conveniences like `.to_string()`.

#### `pub struct Node<T>`

There is probably not a good reason for `Node` to be `pub`. It is dubious for external code to be mucking about with "raw" nodes. If you intend to provide an API that allows back-and-forth traversal, or insertion-at-a-point, consider using a new struct (a cursor) for that so that you can more easily make changes to the internal `Node` type without changing the API.

#### Whitespace

It looks like you're using `rustfmt`, which is great. Also consider putting empty lines between items (functions, structs, `impl` blocks) to create whitespace around the important program elements and make the code more pleasant to read, in the same way that paragraphs and section headings have whitespace around them in written text.

#### `#[allow(unused)]`

`allow(unused)` might be OK when prototyping so that you don't lose track of important warnings among the trivial ones. But once you have something that is relatively complete, you should not continue to hide unused code warnings: those are bugs waiting to happen.

Even while prototyping, I recommend using `allow(dead_code)` (which just allows unused non-`pub` items) instead of the more general `allow(unused)`, which hides a lot more warnings, many of which are helpful at any stage of development.

### [Code with all suggested changes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a99c0d96abb664b4be044c259bddaa3f)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback. I'll keep these tips in mind.